# attach data manually to an observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-routing

I am inside an angular 2 resolve class:

```
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    let figure = 10;
    Observable<any> tests = this.service.getTests(route.params["id"]);
    let data = { tests: tests, figure: figure};
    return data;
  }
```

Before I added that custom figure number only the tests were returned as observable which was not completed yet.

Just adding another object literal with that figure and return it can NOT work...

How can I still return an observable with the unresolved tests AND that extra variable figure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return this.service.getTests(route.params["id"])
   .map(tests=>({tests, figure}));
```

Comment: argh... the map returns observable :P Thanks it worked!

Comment: you can read my article for people who knows angular 1 promises and wnat to move to angular 2 observable at https://medium.com/@juliapassynkova/q-map-to-rxjs-981936a2b22d